# Division algorithm proof without well ordering principle

Tags: constructive-mathematics

Is there a constructive proof of the division algorithm that doesn't invoke the well ordering principle?

Comment: You mean for integers?

Comment: @Zelos Malum Yes, for integers.

Comment: To show that for any $b\ge 0$ and $a\gt 0$ there is a $q$ and $r$ such that $\dots$, do an induction on $b$. Very constructive, albeit a slow construction.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by not using the well-ordering principle. Does using induction count? If so, there's basically nothing you can prove about the integers without using induction. (Related question: are you more interested in the "constructive" part or in the "not using well-ordering" part?)

Comment: My curiosity began with "Oh, WOP is nonconstructive, I wonder if I can get rid of it" So I'm more interested in a constructive proof than just getting rid of WOP. Most constructivists allow proof by induction, no?